# Pass array of objects from apex controller to javascript

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

So I have a some java script where I want to pass a list of Objects from a controller and get a number of fields.  However, I'm having issues passing the individual variables.

However, I'd rather call the controller (I think it's better form)

**Apex:**

```
public List<Activity__C> getActs(){
        myActs = [select Task_Site__c, Activity_Date__c, Activity_Time_Stamp__c,GeoCode__Latitude__s, GeoCode__Longitude__s, workday__r.owner.name
                  from Activity__c 
                  where workday__r.ownerid =: curUser and Activity_Date__c =: filter ];        
        return myActs;
    }
```

**Javascript/VF**

From my controller how can I access the Task_Site__C and other fields via Javascript?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var result = new Array();
        result = '{!Acts}';
        //sforce.connection.sessionId  = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";    
        //sforce.connection.query('select Task_Site__c, Activity_Date__c, Activity_Time_Stamp__c,GeoCode__Latitude__s, GeoCode__Longitude__s, workday__r.owner.name from Activity__c');

        for (var i=0; i < result.length; i++)
        {
            console.log(result[i].Task_site__c);
         }
}
```

Comment: I disagree that querying in your controller is any better than using `sforce.connection`. They wouldn't have opened up the API if they didn't want people using it.

Comment: really, seems like all of the logic is then written in the javascript?

Comment: Yeah I don't see the problem. In fact it seems to be the direction the platform is moving. A bit more dangerous because they don't force you to unit test, but still an acceptable trade-off for performance improvements. Maybe if you get really complicated, but for one query it's much simpler to keep it in one place. Otherwise use serialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My advice is to keep the query in Javascript. Much simpler to keep all the logic in one place than try to route server logic into client code when you can avoid it.

You can, however, use a serialized array property.

```
public String mySerializedList { get; private set; }
public MyConstructor()
{
    mySerializedList = JSON.serialize([/*some query*/]);
}
```

Then in your client-side application you can parse it.

```
var objectArray = JSON.parse('{!JSINHTMLENCODE(mySerializedList)}');
```